# POST request to REST API implemented in PHP

Tags: php, rest, authentication

I am integrating a new front-end survey application using AngularJS with an old RESTful back-end application running on PHP/MySQL.

Currently we require users to sign up in order to complete the survey. Now we would like to allow guest users, i.e. not signed up, to complete the survey. What is the best way to bypass using an auth token (or to generate a new one) for a guest user in PHP? It is simply a POST request that I would like to make as a guest, no other requests are needed.

I am new to PHP. Below is how I am currently creating the survey:

```
  public function createNew(Application $app, Request $request, $now = false)
{
    $data = $request->request->all();
    $token = (isset($data['token']) ? $data['token'] : $app['token']);
    $survey = new Survey($token, 'token');
    $error = new JsonResponse(array('status' => 400, 'message' => "Error while completing the survey"));
    $success = new JsonResponse(array('status' => 200, 'message' => 'Survey completed.')); 
... }
```

basically, a token is currently required and returns an error if it is not provided. Thank you for your help and suggestions.

Comment: We'd probably need to see how it's currently being required to determine what you'd need to do to make it not required. Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: php has no concept of a rest api built in, so unless you show the relevant code (or are using a documented, extremely opinionated framework, and can link the documentation) nobody is going to be able to help much

Comment: @Don'tPanic and Steve -- thank you. I have edited my request and hope it helps.

Comment: Since you're passing the token to the `Survey` constructor I suggest you also add that entire method so we can provide further help, because from that code snippet there's really no way to tell how the token is being handled.